# Calculate total time from 2 input fields on a Webform

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Webform where the user picks a start and end time from a drop list (I truncated the list here).  I want to have the total time calculated automatically.
This is what I have so far and it works, however it does not submit to my DataBase. However, if I change the **span** tag  to an **input** tag it does work and submits however it will not work in Chrome, IE only.

```js
(function(d) {

var
start = d.getElementById('timeStart'),
stop = d.getElementById('timeStop'),
diff = d.getElementById('totaltime');

function textReplace(e, txt) {
if (e.textContent) e.textContent = txt;
    else e.innerText = txt;
}

function addEvent(e, event, handler) {
if (e.addEventListener) e.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    else e.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
}

function selectHours(e) {
return new Date(
    '01/01/1971 ' + e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
).getTime(); 
}

function calcTime(e) {
d = new Date(selectHours(stop) - selectHours(start));
textReplace(diff, d.getUTCHours() + ':' + d.getUTCMinutes());
}

addEvent(start, 'change', calcTime);
addEvent(stop, 'change', calcTime);

})(document);
```

```html
<td style="height: 32px; width: 472px;">
<select name="start" id="timeStart"  style="width:276px;  color: 
black;background-color:#C1D7EB">
<option value="00:00:00">12:00 am</option>
<option value="01:00:00">1:00 am</option>
<option value="01:10:00">1:10 am</option>
<option value="23:00:00">11:00 pm</option>
</select>
</td>

<td style="height: 32px; width: 472px;">
<select name="end" id="timeStop" style="width:276px;  color: 
black;background-color:#C1D7EB">
<option value="00:00:00">12:00 am</option>
<option value="00:30:00">12:30 am</option>
<option value="21:00:00">9:00 pm</option>
<option value="22:00:00">10:00 pm</option>
<option value="23:00:00">11:00 pm</option>
</select>

<td style="width: 472px">
Difference: <span  id="totaltime" name="totaltime"></span>
</td>
```

Comment: What are you using to "Submit" can you provide that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `totaltime` span to an input, you need to modify your `textReplace` function as well.

To set the value of an input value, change the function to something similar to this:

```
   function textReplace(e, txt) {
      e.value = txt;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved it, I greatly appreciate your time helping